# Hide console window by an .exe file executed by a .py script

Tags: python, windows, python-3.5, windows-console

I am trying to hide a console window that pops up from an EXE file. I am running this EXE from my own EXE (a Python script frozen via PyInstaller).

I found out that, whenever I run the script via IDLE or PyCharm, I can hide console windows, and everything works fine. But if I turn my script into an EXE (using `pyinstaller --onefile`), then it's not working.

I tried almost every Google and SO response to my searches about this problem, and still I don't know how can I hide console windows if I turn my script into an EXE file and run it.

The last one I tried:

```
import subprocess
import win32gui
import time

proc = subprocess.Popen(["MyExe.exe"])
# lets wait a bit to app to start
time.sleep(3)

def enumWindowFunc(hwnd, windowList):
    """ win32gui.EnumWindows() callback """
    text = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
    className = win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd)
    #print hwnd, text, className
    if text.find("MyExe.exe") >= 0:
        windowList.append((hwnd, text, className))

myWindows = []
# enumerate thru all top windows and get windows which are ours
win32gui.EnumWindows(enumWindowFunc, myWindows)

# now hide my windows, we can actually check process info from GetWindowThreadProcessId
# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522(VS.85).aspx
for hwnd, text, className in myWindows:
    win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, False)

# as our notepad is now hidden
# you will have to kill notepad in taskmanager to get past next line
proc.wait()
```

Comment: How are you executing the file that pops up with a console window?

Comment: @zwer Simply double-clicking it.

Comment: I mean in the code itself, not how are you launching it. Can you post the whole chain of commands that gets executed?

Comment: @zwer Well, I tried every way to hide CMD, so there is no fixed code, because I tried everything, mostly subprocess module.

Comment: Have you tried to prepend your subprocess calls with `start /b` ?

Comment: @zwer No, where exactly I should prepend it?

Comment: I cannot tell you where exactly as you haven't posted any code. In general, in front of the commands you're using to call your .exe files.

Comment: @zwer check the question please

Comment: Try opening your subprocess as: `subprocess.Popen(["start", "/b", "MyExe.exe"])` if `MyExe.exe` is the one whose command prompt you don't want to show.

Comment: @zwer If I do that, script doesn' find `MyExe.exe`, I got an error `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]`

Comment: Make sure you include the a path to your `MyExe.exe`.

Comment: @zwer But both script and exe file in the same directory, normally I don't use path and it works without the path

Comment: @zwer, `start` is a built-in command of the CMD shell. This problem has nothing to do with CMD. "MyExe.exe" is simply a console application that allocates a new console window if it doesn't inherit one from the parent process. There are multiple ways to address this: via `CreateProcess` `creationflags` (`CREATE_NO_WINDOW` or `DETACHED_PROCESS`) or `STARTUPINFO` (`wShowWindow` set to `SW_HIDE`), or by allocating a hidden console at startup, which child processes can inherit.

Comment: @zwer I am going to put a bounty on this question, eligible in 8 hours.

Comment: @GLHF try what zwer hinted but with shell=True: `subprocess.Popen(["start", "/b", "MyExe.exe"],shell=True)` since `start` is a built-in shell command.

Comment: I don't see how this differs from previous questions. `subprocess.Popen` calls WinAPI `CreateProcess` and provides everything you need to control whether and how the console is allocated in a child process. If you always want the child to get a new console that has no window, then simply use `Popen('A.exe', creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)`. If you want it to always create a hidden window, instead use `si = STARTUPINFO();` `si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;` `subprocess.Popen('A.exe', creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, startupinfo=si)`.

Comment: If you need to interact with its console (e.g. to send `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`) given "B.exe" is not a console application, then begin by allocating your own windowless console by running a dummy CMD process via `p = Popen('cmd.exe', creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW);` `while not AttachConsole(p.pid): sleep(0.25)`. Once attached to its console, use `p.terminate()` to kill the dummy CMD process. To send a child `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` reliably, it should be created as a new group via `creationflags=CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`.

Comment: @eryksun kind of my point in OP previous post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360746/how-to-end-this-this-isnt-a-duplicate-situation-with-the-op.

Comment: @eryksun B.exe is a console application.

Comment: @GLHF, so, without any additional parameters, `Popen('A.exe')` should inherit the console from "B.exe".

Answer (score 6):

you can use -w option in Pyinstaller.

for example,

> pyinstaller -F -w FILENAME

you can learn more by excute

> pyinstaller -h

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Why this answer is having negative points ? The -w option of pyinstaller overrides the default -c option that creates a console for standard i/o. This is similar to the py2exe `setup(console...` vs `setup(window...`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i know im late.You can hide console window in pyinstaller by using `--noconsole`

Such as this:

```
python PyInstaller Filename.py --onefile --noconsole
```

This will hide console window and program will execute normally.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `spec` file - add `console=False` to your `EXE(...)` command:

```
exe = EXE(pyz,
      ...
      console=False )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thinking laterally, a solution might be to run your application from Windows' **Task Scheduler** application* and set the task to `Run whether user is logged on or not`.

The `Run whether user is logged on or not` setting causes the application to run invisibly, meaning no widnows, taskbar icons or console windows will be displayed on-screen.

* Task Scheduler is installed in Windows by default. Type its name into Cortana to run